# Method not running in Android - Java

Tags: java, android

I have a problem, whenever I make a method myself and I want to use it, I run into problems. The program does not give an error, but it does not run. If anyone knows what the problem is, please help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

List item

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CustomToast1(" show text");

    }

    public void CustomToast1(String text) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        View view1 = toast.getView();
        TextView txt1 = view1.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(50, 0, 0, 0));
        txt1.setTextSize(24);
        txt1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        txt1.setWidth(700);
        txt1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        txt1.setCompoundDrawablePadding(40);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the toast view from the toast, to protect the users.

if you want to do this you should use this code:

```
private void CustomToast1(String text) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            View view1 = toast.getView();
            TextView txt1 = (TextView) view1.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.message);
            view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(50, 90, 90, 0));
            txt1.setTextSize(24);
            txt1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            txt1.setWidth(700);
            txt1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            txt1.setCompoundDrawablePadding(40);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        }
        toast.show();
    }
```

if the statement is true then it will display it with it
but for you probably it will display as default but it won't crash.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the default is displayed. Is there a problem with my JDK that runs like this, or the SDK, how can I fix this?

Comment: I think if your sdk version is less than 30 is going to work

Comment: Thank you very much, dear friend, my problem is solved, I hope I can repay your kindness

Comment: It is my pleasure. Have a blessed day!